# On Linux, how do you exempt one user from sticky bit restriction inside of directory

Tags: linux, permissions, rhel

On RHEL 8 I have created a directory for a group. The group members are allowed to create files within the directory, but because of the sticky bit, are disallowed from deleting files created by other group members. I want 1 user that is the head of the group to be allowed to delete other users' files within this directory. However I don't want to give him root on the entire system. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

[`stat(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html), emphasis mine:

> The  sticky  bit  (S_ISVTX)  on a directory means that a file in that directory can be renamed or deleted only by the owner of the file, **by the owner of the directory**, and by a privileged process.

Make that user the user owner of the directory.